# Grails exception, possibly depedency related pertaining to NoClassDefFoundError / BuildableCriteria

Tags: grails

I'm a Grails newb. I'd never touched it before this week.

```
Grails version: 2.5.4
Java version "1.8.0_101"
```

These failures occur when I run the unit tests with:

```
grails test-app
```

I've already changed a number of things and the code appears to compile as-is.

An example of the stack traces I'm seeing:

```
| Failure:  testUpdate(com.xyz.pdq.WidgetControllerTests)
|  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.TestGormEnhancer.getStaticApi(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:188)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.addStaticMethods(GormEnhancer.groovy:118)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.enhance(GormEnhancer.groovy:112)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.enhance(GormEnhancer.groovy:95)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:99)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:179)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

I'm working with the following:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.2"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'  
}
```

By what methodology can I track this down, assuming it is dependency related?

A dependency report shows that I do have this:

```
org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
```

...as noted here in this excerpt from a dependency report:

```
...
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.2
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.0.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.8.RELEASE
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.0.RELEASE
...
```

This pattern repeats in both runtime and test.

Comment: I too am running into the same issue with grails 2.5.5. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, upgrading from 2.2.3 to 2.4.5. Don't suppose anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after reading the [forum answer from Graeme Rocher](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/uAfazRia_SQ). You need to update the hibernate plugin:

`compile ":hibernate4:4.3.10"`